# How I cannot delete pwstr?

Tags: c++, winapi

Please, could someone explain me why this code give me the error in runtime "expression _block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse)"?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    PWSTR path;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &path);
    delete[] path;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...because you did not new it.

Comment: To be precise, because you did not `new[]` it. C++ is not forgiving. You must match each allocation with the right deallocation function.

Comment: You have to use `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer returned from `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, because it uses `CoTaskMemAlloc` internally. `new` and `delete` in C++ use a completely different memory system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the memory is not allocated by `new`. In fact, if you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will see that:

> The calling process is responsible for freeing this resource once it is no longer needed by calling [`CoTaskMemFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I'm new in winapi.

Comment: Could you please explain me why do we need this? I mean new type of allocator. Why do they allocate it by CoTaskMemAlloc, not by malloc or new? (I'm stupid, sorry :) )

Comment: @user3058108 Two good links that you should bookmark: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) which you can search for all the Windows API functions, and [this C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). I'd recommend you search those first before asking questions.

Comment: @user3058108 Windows have many different allocation/free systems, depending on what the memory will be used for. You should *normally* use `new`/`delete` in your program, but for some Windows API functions you need to use other allocation functions.

Comment: @user Windows doesn't know which allocator you like to use. And Windows is runtime agnostics. You might not be used C++. Many other languages are able to call that API function. So Windows uses its own allocator (the COM heap), exports that allocator, and tells you to use it to free the memory. You aren't stupid, you just have not learnt this stuff yet. But you really should get into the habit of reading the docs.

Comment: I think (but haven't checked) that you can use smart pointers for this: `std::unique_ptr<WCHAR> path_ptr(path, &CoTaskMemAlloc);`. This tells C++ that the memory must ultimately be deleted by `CoTaskMemAlloc`, but it relieves you from figuring out exactly _when_ that needs to happen.

Comment: @MSalters It would be `CoTaskMemFree`. But it's generally best just to copy it to a string object, and free the raw memory immediately.

Comment: @MSalters You cannot. `CoTaskMemFree` takes an `LPVOID` argument, while `path` is of type `PWSTR`. You will not get that wrapped into the template-madness.

Comment: @IInspectable: Why would that be a problem? `LPVOID` is just a verbose way to write `void*`, and any pointer converts _to_ `void*`. It's the conversion _from_ `void*` which requires a cast.

Answer (score 1):

There's a more general answer to this (implied by @Joachim's answer):

In Windows, [memory is allocated by a *specific* function, and must be freed by its corresponding deallocator.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx)

Furthermore, even within a specific language (say, C++), memory can be allocated from multiple heaps, and must be freed within that heap.  (C/C++ DLLs, in particular, get their own heap at load time, and memory allocated by that DLL must be freed by that DLL.  Do it wrong, and you get memory corruption and crashes.)

COM has its own allocator/deallocator (`CoTaskMemAlloc`/`CoTaskMemFree`) that is probably the closest thing you'll get to a system-wide allocation function; but even that is mostly used by the shell APIs, and many other Win32 APIs that allocate memory don't use that.